# What is the source of this panel of Emperor Palpatine from the Star Wars comics?

Tags: star-wars, comics, episode-identification

What is the source of this panel of Emperor Palpatine from the *Star Wars* comics?

> [image: Image of Emperor Palpatine from an unidentified Star Wars comic.]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is from *[Age of Rebellion - Darth Vader #1](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Age_of_Rebellion_-_Darth_Vader_1)*

[image]

Comment: Something tells me things are going to go very badly for Governor Smirk very shortly after Vader knows he learned his lesson.

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt - I won't spoil it for you. But yes.